# Grails default app not deploying to tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, grails

I have a very basic grails app which was generated using create-app and creating a simple controller. It works locally, but when I use 'grails war' and deploy it in a tomcat server, there seems to be a database issue. The last 'caused by' in the tomcat logs is

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I have not made any changes to the database configuration generated by create-app (thus using an embedded DB).

The environment is: grails 3, debian 9, tomcat 8.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `grails war` causes the production environment configuration to be used, by default. The db config is different for production and is probably the cause of the problem. You should try `grails -Dgrails.env=development war` or `grails dev war` instead.

Comment: You're right, thanks, this was the cause of the difference between my local environment and tomcat. I'll mark your post as the answer, though could you also please explain why the default prod environment does not work ? I am also a bit struggling to find info on how to configure it for postgres.

Comment: In application.yml, I can see that the dev datasource url is        `url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`
 whereas the prod datasource url is          `url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`
. Is it a file permission issue ?

Comment: Quite likely there is a file permissions issue. You'd have to find out what `./prodDb` resolves to in the context of the app running in tomcat to know for sure. Also the `dbCreate` setting is usually set to `none` in production and may prevent the db from being created.